# Set font size in custom class Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I would like set in may custom class font size. Do you now how I can do this?

CustomButton class

```
  public static readonly BindableProperty PaddingProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Padding),
            typeof(Thickness),
            typeof(CustomButton),
            new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0));

    public static readonly BindableProperty TypeProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Type),
            typeof(TypeEnum),
            typeof(CustomButton),
            TypeEnum.Blue
            );

 public Thickness Padding
    {
        get { return (Thickness)GetValue(PaddingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PaddingProperty, value); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your "custom button" inherits from Xamarin.Forms.Button you can just set its "FontSize" property.

```
public class CustomButton : Xamarin.Forms.Button //Inheriting from Xamarin.Forms.Button!
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty PaddingProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Padding),
            typeof(Thickness),
            typeof(CustomButton),
            new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0));

        public static readonly BindableProperty TypeProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(Type),
                typeof(TypeEnum),
                typeof(CustomButton),
                TypeEnum.Blue
                );

        public Thickness Padding
        {
            get { return (Thickness)GetValue(PaddingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PaddingProperty, value); }
        }

        public CustomButton()
        {
            FontSize = 123; //FontSize property on Xamarin.Forms.Button
        }
    }
```